# Positive continuous function from a Non-negative continuous function on a Tychonoff space

Tags: general-topology

Let $A_1, \ldots, A_m$ be compact subsets of a topological space $X$ and $V_1,\ldots, V_n$ be open subsets in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be distinct points in $X$ and $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ be positive real numbers. Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on $X$ such that $f \geq 0$, $f(x_i) = r_i$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $f(A_j) \subseteq V_j$ for each $1 \leq j \leq m$. If $X$ is a Tychonoff space. How can we find a continuous real-valued function $g$ on $X$ such that $g > 0$, $g(x_i) = r_i$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $g(A_j) \subseteq V_j$ for each $1 \leq j \leq m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\varepsilon>0$ smaller than each $r_i$ and such that $B_\varepsilon(f(x)) \subset V_j$ for all $x \in A_j$. This last condition can be satisfied because $f(A_j)$ is a compact subset of $V_j$ hence $\inf\{|t-s|\colon t\in f(A_j), s\not\in V_j\}>0$.

Then take $g(x) = \max\{f(x),\varepsilon\}$.